# I wanna reduce my image size to 64 KiB for saving in mySql database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, bitmap

I am currently working on an Android App in which I have to send my Image to MySql server using php

I am using BLOB type field in which it restricts me from saving big images. It allows only 64KiB which is not less but is causing problem for big images.

I don't want any good quality but just wanna save it. I compress it using Bitmap.compress method. I am using it with blind faith and don't know if it works well or not.

Here is my converting method:

```
public Bitmap compress(Bitmap bitmap){
    Bitmap original =bitmap;
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, out);
    Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));

    Log.e("Original   dimensions", original.getWidth() + " " + original.getHeight());
    Log.e("Compressed dimensions", decoded.getWidth() + " " + decoded.getHeight());
    return decoded;


}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: And what is you question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
/**
 * reduces the size of the image
 * @param image
 * @param maxSize
 * @return
 */
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 0) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```

use it like:

```
Bitmap scaledImage = getResizedBitmap(photo, 200); //here 200 is maxsize
```

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Sample_photographs)

For highest quality images (Q=100), about 8.25 bits per color pixel is required

So, for Q=100 on an 200x200 image, that would result in `(200 * 200) px * 8.25 bits/px = 330000 bits = ~ 41 kB` which is surely less than 64KB

you can try for other dimension too..

you can also try to make an image using the resized bitmap and compare the actual size of the image..

here is the code:

```
//create a file to write bitmap data
File f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), filename);
f.createNewFile();

//Convert bitmap to byte array
Bitmap bitmap = your bitmap;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

//write the bytes in file
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
fos.write(bitmapdata);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Comment: I don't want to understand too much....I just wanna know if u r sure that it may work. Sorry for rudeness in this comment

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the [Compressor library](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor) to compress the images with more configurable options.

You can add the library to your app from gradle:

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:1.0.4'
}
```

And generate a compressed image by :

```
compressedImage = new Compressor.Builder(this)
        .setMaxWidth(640)
        .setMaxHeight(480)
        .setQuality(75)
        .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP)
        .setDestinationDirectoryPath(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
          Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath())
        .build()
        .compressToFile(actualImage);
```